# Why is my screen is garbled while installing Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, installation, reinstall

I am trying to install Debian on my old Lenovo IdeaPad 330 PC previously running on Windows 10. After entering the Debian installer, the screen has suddenly become garbled:

[image: The Screenshot]

I am unsure as to what to do in such a scenario. I am afraid if I exit or power off my PC at this stage, it might make the PC inaccessible. Obviously, I cannot go ahead with the installation process like this. How do I restart the installation process? And why has the screen become garbled like so?

---

**Update**: So I finally powered off my PC and started it again to continue the installation process, but after the initial installer menu the screen becomes garbled, no matter how many times I reload it.

Comment: Linux installers sometimes have a “safe graphics” mode that you could try. Not too sure about Debian, haven’t installed it recently.

Comment: try using an external monitor

Comment: @DanielB Indeed, Ubuntu and derivatives have a "safe graphics" mode but it's a new thing. This same problem ocurred more than a decade before the safe mode with certian Nvidia graphics which I suspect is the problem here. In the basence of the safe mode user have to boot the live session with `nomodeset` and then install Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're trying to install Debian and not Ubuntu? Ubuntu (or derivatives), especially now with the aforementioned "safe graphics" mode -and- the possibility of automatically install the required Nvidia drivers is much easier.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I wanted a lightweight distro without unnecessary baggage and I had heard criticisms of Ubuntu and its Snap app store. I ended up making the bootable flash drive all over again with some extra firmware installed (the unofficial version) and it ended up installing fine.